# How to blur/ feather the edges of an object in an image using Opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

The objective is to blur the edges of a selected object in an image.

I've done the steps to obtain the contours of the object by using the following code:

```
image = cv2.imread('path of image')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

I am also able to plot the contour using:

`cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)`

Now I want to make use of the points stored in `contours` to blur / feather the edge of the object, perhaps using gaussian blur. How am I able to achieve that?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Similar to what I have mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55039717/how-to-blur-the-image-according-to-segmentation-map/55047704#55047704), you can do it in the following steps:

- Load original image and find contours.
- Blur the original image and save it in a different variable.
- Create an empty mask and draw the detected contours on it.
- Use np.where() method to select the pixels from the mask (contours) where you want blurred values and then replace it.

---

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('./asdf.jpg')
blurred_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (21, 21), 0)
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[2]
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, (255,255,255),5)
output = np.where(mask==np.array([255, 255, 255]), blurred_img, image)
```

[image: Original image]

[image: Detected contours]

[image: Blurred edges]

Comment: note: that `[2]` after the threshold() call is bound to fail because threshold() only returns two things. I can't find documentation that shows this ever having been anything else. best to just write `(rv, thresh) = cv.threshold...`