# Convert a binary mask to non binary (Possibly using refine edge?)

Tags: python, binary, mask

In Photoshop, going into Select and Mask doing Refine Edge using a radius of 4 px gives me the right image in the below screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHbZW.png)

I want to recreate this process in Python. How would I go about converting my binary image on the left, to the non binary image on the right? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should find what is doing the Refine edge algorithm and try to reproduce into python.

I have no ideas in my mind for this kind of reconstruction because you have loss of information right at the beginning with your binary image.

hope you will find what you want :)

Comment: Sorry, loss of information? I am supposed to have the binary image. I don't get it because I have lost information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55068554/18266788
maybe try this idk if it going to work