# How can I fade the edges of a transparent image in Python using PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to fade the edges of an image that has a transparent background.
Is there a way to do this in Python using the PIL library?

I tried using the `ImageFilter.BLUR` filter but I can't seem to find a way to fade the edges only.

Comment: Are you trying to blur the edges of the subject of the image or the edges of the whole picture (including transparent background)?

Comment: @SanguineL I'm trying to blur the edges of the subject of the image, it's a non-rectangular shape basically.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55068554/9731347)? Perhaps it is what you are looking for.

Comment: @SanguineL yes I've seen it, however, it uses OpenCV and I'm looking for a way to get a similar effect using PIL.

Comment: I mean unless you have a legitimate reason not to use OpenCV, it really is the best way to go about doing that. There is an ImageFilter.filter(FIND_EDGES) method that can be used to create a mask, which you could then blur and combine with the original image, but I had some trouble while attempting that (mostly because the FIND_EDGES method does not have a width parameter as OpenCV does).