# How to do remove jagged edges of an object in an image with python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have tried to search and found two solutions that could solve the problem I have but are not working by my side. I want to remove the jagged edges or **smooth** the image attached. I have tried to implement the following codes

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
os.chdir("F:/Examples")
image = cv2.imread("image1.jpeg")
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (21, 21), 0)
mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)

output = np.where(mask==np.array([255, 255, 255]), blur, image)
cv2.imwrite("", output)
```

The above codes returns unchanged image as if the applied mask didn't work. Here is the input image

I also tried to implement some solutions from different links including ([How to blur the image according to segmentation map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55039717/how-to-blur-the-image-according-to-segmentation-map/55047704#55047704)) without success. Any help will be acknowledged 
While the edges or the external contour should be clear as in this image

Comment: how do you expect the output to look like? Any examples for bevor and after would help to understand

Comment: As shown in the edited question the whole image should have clear contours not  jagged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I almost managed to solve it.

The main problem is that the contour is partially curved, and partially with straight lines.

Explanations are in the comments:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from scipy.interpolate import splprep, splev

im = cv2.imread('image1.jpeg')

bk = im.copy()

# Fill background with black color
cv2.floodFill(im, None, seedPoint=(1,1), newVal=(0, 0, 0), loDiff=(5, 5, 5), upDiff=(5, 5, 5))
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

ret, thresh_gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 5, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Use "open" morphological operation for removing small contours (noise)
thresh_gray = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh_gray, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5)));

# Background
bk[(thresh_gray > 0)] = 0
bk = cv2.morphologyEx(bk, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (20,20)));
#cv2.imshow('bk', bk)

# Foreground
fg = im.copy()
tmm_fg = cv2.morphologyEx(fg, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (20,20)));
fg_gray = cv2.cvtColor(fg, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
fg[(fg_gray==0)] = tmm_fg[(fg_gray==0)]


#thresh_gray = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh_gray, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (50,50)));

# Find contours (there is only one contour)
# _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh_gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)  # 3 outputs works only in OpenCV 3. [-2:] is used for compatibility.
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh_gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2:]  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291581/how-to-use-cv2-findcontours-in-different-opencv-versions
c = contours[0]

# Smooth contour
# https://agniva.me/scipy/2016/10/25/contour-smoothing.html
x,y = c.T
x = x.tolist()[0]
y = y.tolist()[0]
tck, u = splprep([x,y], u=None, s=1.0, per=1)
u_new = np.linspace(u.min(), u.max(), 150)
x_new, y_new = splev(u_new, tck, der=0)
res_array = [[[int(i[0]), int(i[1])]] for i in zip(x_new,y_new)]
smoothened = np.asarray(res_array, dtype=np.int32)

# Build a mask
mask = np.zeros_like(thresh_gray)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [smoothened], -1, 255, -1)

# For testig
test_im = cv2.cvtColor(thresh_gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
cv2.drawContours(test_im, [smoothened], 0, (0, 255, 0), 1)

res = bk
res[(mask > 0)] = fg[(mask > 0)]

cv2.imshow('test_im', test_im)
cv2.imshow('res', res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate

Comment: I am getting error  `  _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh_gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

builtins.ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)`

Comment: @SIslam I updated my answer. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291581/how-to-use-cv2-findcontours-in-different-opencv-versions) for details. `_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours` is compatible with OpenCV 3